# Running Magento 2 on a subdomain of Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, multistore, multidomain

I did a fair amount of research before posting this question to ensure I am not asking a repeated question.
I am newbie to Magento, and I would like to get your advice on the below workflow:

I have a **Magento 1.9** Installed on **www.samplestore.com** (it's a small store), and right now, I am thinking to open **samplestore.com** for another country market. (let's say France)

I understand Magento supports multiple stores, However, I want to use this as an opportunity to discover Magento 2.0, instead of sticking with 1.9.

Thus, we are thinking to install, Magento 2.0 on a subdomain. (Example: samplestore.com/FR/) and keep **Magento 1.9** on the main store.

I know by doing this, all the customers and orders, and sales will be isolated from the main store, however, **my questions are**:

Does the above scenario makes any sense to implement?

How can I redirect all the terrific from France to /FR/ subdomain automatically? (Is it something that has to be handled at the server level and not Magento Level?)

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the difference between subdomain and language as paramater:

- Subdomain - `fr.samplestore.com`
- Language/Parameter - `samplestore.com/fr`

I would recommend using the subdomain approach with having

- Magento 1 on `samplestore.com` and
- Magento 2 on `fr.samplestore.com`

and setting up two different vhosts (in Apache or Nginx). To make sure all traffic coming from France is handled by your `fr.samplestore.com` domain is something that cannot be handled by Magento. For that I recommend you make yourself comfortable with Geo IP and redirection on web server level (see http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/).

Answer (score 0):

very bad idea.
better way is:

1. migrate to Magento 2
2. buy `samplestore.fr`
3. configure DNS and store view code
4. profit!

This way you will keep everything in sync and easy to manage.